# Allow amparsand (&) in model while Sanitize using HtmlSanitizer C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, html-sanitizing

I am using the HtmlSanitizer to Sanitize the url as well as the html. When I am passing the & from the UI the Sanitize converts to **&amp**;

I want to allow the & to be get passed in the model. I used the below code from the api

```
_sanitizer.AllowedSchemes.Add("&");
```

**complete code**

```
public void SetValue(object target, object value)
            {
                if (value is string s)
                {
                    _sanitizer.AllowedSchemes.Add("&");
                    var encodedString = _sanitizer.Sanitize(s);
                    _targetProperty.SetValue(target, encodedString);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Shouldn't get here as we checked for string properties before setting this value provider
                    _targetProperty.SetValue(target, value);
                }
            }
```

The above code conver the & to **&amp**. Is there any way to allow & in the  HtmlSanitizer

References
https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution after the research. Create a custom html mapper

```
private string Sanitize(string text)
        {
            return Sanitizer.Sanitize(text, "", NoEntityMarkupFormatter.Instance);
        }

        private class NullEntityResolver : IEntityProvider
        {
            public string GetSymbol(string name)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private class NoEntityMarkupFormatter : IMarkupFormatter
        {
            internal static readonly NoEntityMarkupFormatter Instance = new NoEntityMarkupFormatter();
            private static readonly IMarkupFormatter defaultFormatter = HtmlMarkupFormatter.Instance;

            public string Text(string text)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
                    switch (text[i])
                    {
                        // Change: Don't do this as we aren't decoding incoming entities
                        // case '&': sb.Append("&amp;"); break;
                        case '\xA0': sb.Append("&nbsp;"); break;
                        case '>': sb.Append("&gt;"); break;
                        case '<': sb.Append("&lt;"); break;
                        default: sb.Append(text[i]); break;
                    }
                return sb.ToString();
            }

            public string Comment(IComment comment)
            {
                return defaultFormatter.Comment(comment);
            }

            public string Processing(IProcessingInstruction processing)
            {
                return defaultFormatter.Processing(processing);
            }

            public string Doctype(IDocumentType doctype)
            {
                return defaultFormatter.Doctype(doctype);
            }

            public string OpenTag(IElement element, bool selfClosing)
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append('<');

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Prefix))
                    sb.Append(element.Prefix).Append(':');

                sb.Append(element.LocalName);

                foreach (var attribute in element.Attributes)
                    sb.Append(" ").Append(Instance.Attribute(attribute));

                sb.Append('>');
                return sb.ToString();
            }

            public string CloseTag(IElement element, bool selfClosing)
            {
                return defaultFormatter.CloseTag(element, selfClosing);
            }

            public string Attribute(IAttr attr)
            {
                var namespaceUri = attr.NamespaceUri;
                var localName = attr.LocalName;
                var value = attr.Value;
                var sb = new StringBuilder();

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(namespaceUri))
                    sb.Append(localName);
                else if (Is(namespaceUri, NamespaceNames.XmlUri))
                    sb.Append(NamespaceNames.XmlPrefix).Append(':').Append(localName);
                else if (Is(namespaceUri, NamespaceNames.XLinkUri))
                    sb.Append(NamespaceNames.XLinkPrefix).Append(':').Append(localName);
                else if (Is(namespaceUri, NamespaceNames.XmlNsUri))
                    sb.Append(XmlNamespaceLocalName(localName));
                else
                    sb.Append(attr.Name);

                sb.Append('=').Append('"');

                for (var i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
                    switch (value[i])
                    {
                        // Change: Don't do this as we aren't decoding incoming entities
                        // case '&': temp.Append("&amp;"); break;
                        case '\xA0': sb.Append("&nbsp;"); break;
                        case '"': sb.Append("&quot;"); break;
                        default: sb.Append(value[i]); break;
                    }

                return sb.Append('"').ToString();
            }

            private static bool Is(string a, string b)
            {
                return string.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.Ordinal);
            }

            private static string XmlNamespaceLocalName(string name)
            {
                return Is(name, NamespaceNames.XmlNsPrefix) ? name : string.Concat(NamespaceNames.XmlNsPrefix, ":");
            }
        }

        private static readonly Configuration TextWithoutEntityConfiguration =
            new Configuration().WithCss(e => e.Options = new CssParserOptions
            {
                IsIncludingUnknownDeclarations = true,
                IsIncludingUnknownRules = true,
                IsToleratingInvalidConstraints = true,
                IsToleratingInvalidValues = true
            }).With(new NullEntityResolver());

        private static readonly HtmlSanitizer Sanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer
        {
            HtmlParserFactory = () => new HtmlParser(TextWithoutEntityConfiguration)
        };
```

Reference 
https://gist.github.com/nallar/d91160cd6a30b15ccb5265677f0cf29a

Comment: You can also make a new implementation inheriting from HtmlMarkupFormatter and override the Attribute method. Or try to pass HtmlMarkupFormatter instance directly.